# Upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2 update 1 function preview not working

Tags: phantomjs, c1-cms

I got this message in server log:

```
PhantomJs server unable to complete HTTP requests, preventing C1 Function preview images from being generated. 
Composite.Core.WebClient.BrowserRenderException: ERROR, page.onResourceTimeout: "Network timeout on resource.", URL: "http://tempvala/Composite/blank.aspx"
Request: .CMSAUTH_-1796214875_757602046,41A53DFC3B8F0A3FCEC9860340804062FDA6CECBD2DF57EDF765A3E495C56F518A1F9195D76BC80B9F58B8CC7884B44B06DF96CEAAFC30717BDF00A0D80C7D955C4B3A4A2880C8018726C093824B5B0599D841C96ECA0B93501535F7B364BDA7,tempvala|http://tempvala/Composite/blank.aspx|C:\Sites\PublicUpgrade42\App_Data\Composite\Cache\Temp\phantomtest.png|test
   at Composite.Core.WebClient.BrowserRender.PhantomServer.RenderUrl(HttpCookie authenticationCookie, String url, String tempFilePath, String mode, String& output)
   at Composite.Core.WebClient.BrowserRender.CheckServerAvailability(HttpContext context, HttpCookie authenticationCookie)
```

I dont know what to do about this, and cant find any answers on internet.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing the website from the same machine where the website is hosted?

If not, it is required to map the host name 'tempvala' to 127.0.0.1 on the machine where the website is hosted as well. Function preview is generated by PhantomJs that is making HTTP requests, it is possible that it is failing to resolve the host name.